# Cannot get 'index' node detail by getAttribute

Tags: java, selenium, appium

[image]I am new to Appium automation and I'm trying to retrieve 'index' node value by using .getAttribute in my code but am not able to. 
Is there any way that i can retrieve index of a particular element locator?

```
String x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+str+"']/../..")).getAttribute("index");
```

Comment: can you paste you code here ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We cannot help you with code we cannot see.

Comment: String x  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='"+str+"']/../..")).getAttribute("index");

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_ please?

Comment: i do not have the html but I've uploaded the hierarchy of the element displayed in Android device monitor

Comment: Are you trying to get the index value of that element or its parent element?

Comment: Make sure you are passing India Gate as str value

Comment: I am trying to get the index value of either parent or the child any one will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve index value using `getAttribute()` method, instead use something like a counter to identify the number of the times the text field occurs on the screen.

```
By mySelector = By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView");
List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(mySelector);
int count = 0;
for(WebElement e : myElements) {

    count++;
    if(e.getText().equals(str1)) {
        System.out.println(count); //This will give the index value
    }
    else{
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the **index** *attribute* from the node you can write a `function()` as follows :

```
public void viewIndex(String str)
{
    String x = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[.='" + str + "']")).getAttribute("index");
}
```

Now, from your `main()` or `@Test` annotated Class call the function `viewIndex()` with the intended `text` as follows :

```
viewIndex("India Gate");
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` doesn't throws any light on whats wrong happening. Update the question with your current code trial and error trace log.