# print index of an element from the search list in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

i am using maps.mapmyindia.com, when i am searching for a state or city it shows a list of search list now i need to print the index of the exact match of my search, i want to print that index on the consol, thanks in advance. i have tried this code

```
WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='directions-route-text']"));
            String str = "Nehru Place";
            WebElement li = list.findElement(By.xpath("*[. = str]"));
        List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        System.out.println(myElements.indexOf(li));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot get 'index' node detail by getAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48823391/cannot-get-index-node-detail-by-getattribute)

Comment: What is it printing?

Comment: WebElement list = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mCSB_container']"));
  String str="Nehru Place" 
  List<WebElement> myElements = driver.findElements(By.name(str));
  System.out.println(myElements.indexOf(str));

Comment: i have changed the code and now it always prints -1

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<WebElement> myElements = list.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
 ArrayList<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
 int listsize= myElements.size();
 for(int i=0;i<listsize;i++)
 {
  as.add(myElements.get(i).getText()); 
 }
 System.out.println(as.indexOf(str));
```

Try above code:

Comment: List<WebElement> list = div.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
       Thread.sleep(5000);
       int listsize= list.size();
       for(int i=0;i<listsize;i++)
       {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(list.get(i).getText()); 
        if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Nehru Place"))
        {
          System.out.println(i+"=index of Nehru Place");
        }
       }